# Bonded Object and Fashionable Trait

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

A question from one of my Pathfinder Society players:

"...I want to take the fashionable trait for Taldor, and if I had a (bonded item) ring or amulet would that count towards the gold needed to be worn to receive the bonus?"

I think it should, but there is no set price for the bonded item (that I can see), so it's hard to calculate the cost.

Does the bonded item contribute to the cost and, if so, how much?

Comment: there is discussion about the topic here, it looks like the consensus is no: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2jvih?Wizards-and-Fashionable-Trait

Comment: Since this is PFS: When in doubt, the answer is "No." Other GMs might disagree with you, even though they are highly unlikely to even notice 80gp differences. Also note that social scenarios are not uncommon in PFS, and every character is likely to end up owning fancy clothing in the long term. That, and not wearing fancy clothes is a disgrace to Taldans all over Golarion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything in the RAW regarding this, but if he were my player, I'd simply have him spend the 80 gp (so he doesn't gain an unfair advantage, i.e. the equivalent of free money from a class feature...), and have this money applied towards improving the appearance of the bonded item (a nice gem or delicate filigree on the ring / amulet).

Thematically, I don't see any problem with using a bonded item along with this trait - this is certainly not as drastic as fighting using a bonded weapon, which the RAW obviously allow...

Answer (score 0):

Bonded items are described as being masterwork items, so your arcane bond would logically have some value. An arcane bond created post character creation would have a value of whatever you paid for the item (not including the ritual fee).

The hard part is the value of the free arcane bond item you get at character creation. That's something that would have to be decided by the DM. Jewelry value is listed as simply "Varies" so not a lot of help there. Personally if I was DM, I would take any value out of the free 10 gold clothing budget. You might also argue that it shouldn't have any value at all. Or you might argue that since they're masterwork they should be worth much more.